# Matlab - how does contour plot generating levels automatically?

Tags: matlab, contour

I am using contourf to generate filled contour plots on MatLab with specified levels number.

According to the documents (https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourf.html#mw_9088c636-4036-4e00-bd43-f6c5632b63ec)
It says *Specify levels as a scalar value n to display the contour lines at n automatically chosen levels (heights).*

I am wondering how does it choose the threshold automatically? What is the algorithm of choosing the thresholds? Take level as 1 as an example.

Many thanks!

Comment: I assume it takes max/min and divides that in equal n chuncks. Why do you want to know it?

Comment: Its a plotting function, please do not use a plotting function output for thresholding!! Use actual tresholding code!

Comment: But I still wanna know how does it work..

Comment: “I tested it and it seems it's not just dividing into n chuncks.” Maybe post this test in your question. Would give us something to discuss around.

Answer (score 3):

As said in the comments, it just makes sure there are `n` dividing lines between your max and min.

Proof:

```
n=10;
z=peaks;
[m,c]=contour(z,10,'ShowText','on');
levels=linspace(min(z(:)),max(z(:)),n+2);
isequal(c.LevelList,levels(2:end-1))
```